# Which lens to use to get all keys in an Aeson.Object?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, aeson, lenses

I'm looking at https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/lens-aeson-1.0.2/Data-Aeson-Lens.html and trying to find out a lens which can give me all they keys from an `Object`. Conceptually, I'm looking for the following:

```
allKeys :: Value -> Maybe [Text]
allKeys v = v ^? _Object . keys -- `keys` is not an actual lens!
```

The closest that I can *possibly* get to, is by using [`members`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-12.1/lens-aeson-1.0.2/Data-Aeson-Lens.html#v:members), but it doesn't seem the easiest/fastest/shorted way to achieve this.

Comment: What solution involving `members` do you find lacking?

Comment: It's giving me a `[(Text, Value)]` and I have to process it further to get `[Text]`. It _seems_ like there should be a more straightforward way of doing this.

Comment: `v ^@.. members` does not wrap the list in `Maybe`. Is it fine to drop the `Maybe`?

Comment: What's the maybe supposed to be for? A value _always_ has keys, even if it has no keys.

Comment: The value may not be an object. Perhaps he wants to tell between an empty object and a string.

Comment: the result is a `Maybe [Text]` because the input to the function is a `Value`. If the input to the function is an `Object` then the result can be a `[Text]`

Answer (score 1):

```
toKeysList :: Value -> [Text]
toKeysList = toListOf $ members . asIndex
```

Comment: How does one actually use this? eg `x ^? _Right . (ix 0) . <??>` -- what do I put in place of `<??>` to get all keys of the object?

Comment: Assuming that `x ^? _Right . ix 0` would have type `Maybe Value`: `x ^.. _Right . ix 0 . members . asIndex`. My answer was wrong, edited!

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably use what @Gurkenglas suggested, or

```
view (_Object . to HM.keys)
    :: (AsValue s, MonadReader s m)
    => m [Text]
```

I find it's important to note that `lens` doesn't really shine there; for a reason.
The keys of an object are part of its "shape". `lens` works nicely when you don't need to change shape. So you can *get* the keys, but you cannot do much else, i.e. you cannot *set* or *modify* them.

Comment: `at` lets you work with an object as a map `k :-> Maybe v`, which can be edited to add and remove keys.

Answer (score 0):

To add on to @Gurkenglas' answer, there needs to be a slight update in `toKeysList` due to the type signature of the `members` function changing from `AsValue t => IndexedTraversal' Text t Value` to `AsValue t => IndexedTraversal' Key t Value` in [`lens-aeson-1.2`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-aeson-1.2/changelog). Here is the new version of the code:

```hs
toKeysList :: Value -> [Text]
toKeysList = toListOf $ members . asIndex . from _Key
```